# Why is there a difference between templated recursive calls and fold expressions with type cast or promotion?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, fold

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class... Types>
class Test {
 public:
  Test()
    : format_({
      [&] {
      if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Types, int64_t>) {
        return "%ld ";
      } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Types, int32_t>) {
        return "%d ";
      } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Types, double>) {
        return "%f ";
      }
      }() ...
    }) {}

  template<typename T, typename ... Args>
  void print_recursive(T && v, Args && ... args) {
    size_t i = sizeof...(Types) - sizeof...(args) - 1;
    printf(format_[i], std::forward<T>(v));
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
      print_recursive(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  void print_fold(Types && ... args) {
    size_t i = 0;
    ([&]{
      printf(format_[i++], args);
    }(), ...);
    printf("\n");
  }

 private:
  std::array<const char*, sizeof...(Types)> format_;
};

int main() {
  Test<int64_t, int32_t, double> t;
  t.print_recursive(1.0, 2, 3.0);
  t.print_fold(1.0, 2, 3.0);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 2 3.000000 
1 2 3.000000
```

Built and ran with the following:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++17 && ./test
```

Compiler Info:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

In the above example, the `format_` array is defined using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and used in both print calls. Each print call has the same format specifier for the same index. Each print call has the same args past to it as well. However the output is different for the two. Why is that the case?

**EDIT:**
Adding the correct recursive call that will convert the function arguments to the class template types first before making the recursive call as recommended by @n. m.

```
  void print_recursive(Types && ... args) {
    print_recursive_impl(std::forward<Types>(args)...);
  }

  template<typename T, typename ... Args>
  void print_recursive_impl(T && v, Args && ... args) {
    size_t i = sizeof...(Types) - sizeof...(args) - 1;
    printf(format_[i], std::forward<T>(v));
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
      print_recursive_impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hm, I don't have a laptop next to me, so could you please put this code into compiler explorer and share the link.

Comment: Are you running on linux or windows?

Comment: running on linux, @Dmitry https://godbolt.org/z/sjnhYEexb

Comment: C format string in template code is very poor idea.

Comment: @MarekR this is more of a minimal reproducible example for a similar issue I am seeing. I use fold expressions for defining the schema of a parquet stream writer, with the class being templated with the schema types. However when actually writing out to the parquet stream writer, the recursive call errors out due to mismatching types, but the fold expression does not. I could try posting this as another question

Comment: Just use `fmt` library instead playing around with C-format strings (was incorporated into C++20).

Comment: @ajoseps
Just note `void print_recursive(Types && ... args) {` Types here is no longer a forwarding reference. That basically means "only r-value references of type Types"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You print double as an integer in the recursive call. That's a UB or some other nonsense.

In the fold version you convert them to the appropriate types first.

Comment: @NathanOliver in the call `void print_fold(Types && ... args)` this is not a template function. `Types...` are the class template parameters

Comment: is there any way to make the recursive call use the class template parameters?

Comment: @ajoseps You can write something like `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::tuple<Types...>, std::tuple<T, Args...>>);`

Comment: how would you define `first_arg` vs `rest_args` when using the class templates?

Comment: @ajoseps you can split it into two calls, first one converts them into the right types and then you apply the recursion.

Comment: @ajoseps
Smth like that https://godbolt.org/z/4h1neG7Kd

Comment: @Dmitry that's not quite what I'm looking for. That just adds a check to see if the args match up with the class template parameters, and fails out otherwise. I would like it to autocast to the correct type by applying the variadic class template types to the argument list first

Comment: @ajoseps "is there any way to make the recursive call use the class template parameters" Define a wrapper using template parameters, and make a call to print_recursive from there.

Comment: wow that's so obvious/simple in retrospect, thank you